# div that deforms when a user zooms

Tags: css, html

I want my site adapts to different resolutions. So I used the css code to adapt it but when I zoom with my mouse (CTRL + Mouse Scroll) it deforms the page completely.

Here are the pictures to show what it looks like : 
Default : http://www.picamatic.com/view/10090840_defaut/

 x500 : http://www.picamatic.com/view/10090842_x500/

I do not know how to fix this, here is my code: 
HTML :

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="sms">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 85%;
    height: 90%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.sms {
    position: relative;
    left: 2%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
    width: 42.5%;
    top: 2%;
    height: 5%;
}
```

I hope I was quite understandable and if possible have any help.
 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain what is really happening and how to fix this, but maybe this alternate solution will help:

you could disable zooming by using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

and use @media queries in your CSS to adapt to every screen resolution.

Example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  NORMAL-CSS-SELECTOR-HERE (e.g. #id / .class / body) {
    CSS HERE (e.g. font-size / border)
  }
}
```